# Nodejs / React / Deploying to linux / pb compatibility with serve vs node

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have clone my repo to my linux server and rebuild the modules with

```
npm install
```

Then I used

```
serve -s build
```

Which I had to install with

```
npm install serve
```

though serve-index and serve_static were present in my config.json

But here is the warning

> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for serve@14.0.1: wanted:
> {"node":">= 14"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"}) npm WARN
> notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: serve@14.0.1

In my windows dev I have node v16.15.0

So why would I get another version in linux when I use npm install ?

**Edit**

Actually `npm ls  --level=0` gives this output (which seems to me that correct version of node is installed)

[image: npm ls]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the node version installed on your linux server which seems to be 10.19.0 while one of the package you use require node >= 14 You can verify with your node version `node --version`

You can use any node version manger to change version with ease, I quite like [volta](https://volta.sh/)